# Qt5 Deploy on Linux - Sem instalação

Tags: c++, qt, deploy

Estou desenvolvendo uma solução no QtCreator Qt version 5.4.2.
Bem, estou com o seguinte problema: Quando executo em minha máquina e em qualquer Ubuntu Vivid (15.04) ela funciona. Mas quando tento rodar no Ubuntu 14.04 LTS dá erro.
Existem modos de fazer essa aplicação funcionar em várias distros. Pelo que eu pesquisei a melhor é a:

You can write a startup script for your application, where you modify the dynamic linker configuration (e.g., adding your application's directory to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
[Site Fonte](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html)

Só que eu não consigo descobrir como fazer isso ou o script. Eu preciso que essa aplicação funcione sem ser .deb, ou seja sem precisar ser instalada e sem que o usuário precise instalar qualquer coisa para que ela funcione. Alguém que já trabalhe com QT pode me ajudar? Att

Answer (score 1):

Pra fazer isso você precisa saber como linkar o executável às bibliotecas que você está distribuindo e que bibliotecas distribuir.

### Linkando executável às bibliotecas

Existem duas maneiras de linkar o seu executável às bibliotecas do Qt que você está distribuindo com o seu pacote: criar um script e exportar o `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` e alterar o `RPATH` do executável.

#### Criar script Bash

Maneira número 1 é a que foi citada lá no site: criar um script adicionando o diretório contento suas bibliotecas para a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Como você está distribuindo um programa para Linux, recomendo fazer um script Bash. Considerando que todas as bibliotecas e o executável estejam em um diretório chamado `app`, um exemplo de script seria:

```
# Caminho absoluto para o diretório onde o script se encontra
# Achei esse truque no SO internacional, mas não tenho o link salvo
DIRETORIO_ATUAL="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)"

# Coloca o diretório com as bibliotecas no LD_LIBARY_PATH:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${DIRETORIO_ATUAL}/app"

# Executa o aplicativo:
./app/aplicativo
```

Há vários tutoriais e dicas ótimos na internet sobre o Bash no Google e no próprio SO, então dê uma pesquisada que você vai estar de boa – e poste suas dúvidas aqui no SO em Português.

#### Alterar `RPATH`

Outra maneira de linkar as bibliotecas ao seu aplicativo é alterar o `RPATH` dele. O `RPATH` é uma lista de diretórios inserida no binário do seu executável na hora da compilação; o `ld`, que é o programa que faz a linkagem das bibliotecas ao executável olha, entre outros lugares, no `RPATH` do aplicativo para determinar onde procurar por bibliotecas.

Se você estiver usando qmake, eu não recomendo esse método, pois o qmake dá uns probleminhas pra modificar o `RPATH` do binário. Se você estiver usando o CMake (o que eu recomendo), é relativamente simples:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "\$ORIGIN")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
```

Sendo `\$ORIGIN` o diretório onde o executável se encontra. Se você quisesse, por exemplo, colocar todas as bibliotecas em um diretório chamado `diretorio`, você usaria `"\$ORIGIN/diretorio"`.

### Bibliotecas necessárias

#### Dependências

Depende bastante do que você está utilizando, mas a distribuição mais básica do Qt em um SO como, por exemplo, o Ubuntu, precisa das seguintes bibliotecas:

- `libQt5Core.so.5`
- `libQt5DBus.so.5`
- `libQt5Gui.so.5`
- `libQt5Widgets.so.5`
- `libicudata.so.53`
- `libicui18n.so.53`
- `libicuuc.so.53`

Isso presumindo-se o Qt 5.4. A versão das `libicu*` pode mudar dependendo da versão do Qt – e, a essa altura, recomendo você usar o Qt 5.6, que é a última versão estável e que é uma versão de suporte estendido.

Sem as bibliotecas acima, o programa nem inicia. Se você for rodar num terminal e uma biblioteca que o executável depende estiver faltando, uma mensagem parecida com essa vai aparecer:

```
./aplicativo: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Widgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Para verificar se todas as bibliotecas que o executável depende estão presentes, use o [`ldd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html).

#### Plugins

Além disso, você também precisa distribuir os plugins. Essa é a parte mais complicada, porque é algo que não dá problema em sua máquina, já que ela tem todos os plugins instalados e todas as variáveis de ambiente configuradas, além de os plugins necessários não aparecerem no `ldd`.

Você encontra os plugins na pasta `$QTDIR/plugins`. No Linux, o mínimo de plugins que você tem que distribuir são os seguintes:

- `platforms/libqxcb.so`
- `platformthemes/libqgtk2.so`, se você quiser que o aplicativo adote o tema do sistema no Ubuntu e no GNOME

Importante frizar que a estrutura dos diretórios dos plugins *deve ser mantida* – isto é, se você simplesmente jogar o `libqxcb.so` dentro do diretório das suas bibliotecas, não vai funcionar.

Basicamente, é isso. Talvez você ainda tenha que fazer mais algumas coisas, mas fazer isso é meio que um processo de tentativa e erro, às vezes. Espero que meu guia seja útil!